# The UILabel is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a ContentPageViewController class, it has the IBOutlet stuff. I write my getter of ContentPageViewController in the ViewController like the following code.

ContentPageViewController.h

```
@interface ContentPageViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *busName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *busTime;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *busType;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instantiation from a storyboard
    ContentPageViewController *page = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentPageViewController"];
    self.page = page;

    // send url request
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.apb-shuttle.info/now" ]];

    [self sendURLRequest:request];
    // add the view of ContendPageViewController into ViewController
    [self.view addSubview:self.page.view];
}

// It works if i remove the following code
- (ContentPageVC *)page
{
    if (_page) _page = [[ContentPageViewController alloc] init];

    return _page;
}
```

Nothing happened when I updated it. And it gave me a nil.

```
- (void)updateUI 
{
     // I got null here
     NSLog("%@", self.page.busName)
     // The spacing style font
     NSDictionary *titleAttributes = @{
                                  NSKernAttributeName: @10.0f
                                 };
     NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSKernAttributeName: @5.0f
                            };

     self.page.busName.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:bus.name
                                                             attributes:titleAttributes];
     self.page.busTime.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:bus.depart
                                                             attributes:titleAttributes];
     self.page.busType.attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:bus.note
                                                             attributes:attributes];

}
```

The following code is when I called the updateUI:

```
- (void)sendURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)requestObj
{
    isLoading = YES;
    [RequestHandler PerformRequestHandler:requestObj withCompletionHandler:^(NSDictionary *data, NSError *error) { 
        if (!error) {
            bus = [JSONParser JSON2Bus:data];
            // Add the bus object into the array.
            [self.busArray addObject: bus];
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock: ^{
                [self updateUI];
                isLoading = NO;
            }];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }];
}
```

But it worked if I removed the getter above. 
I have no idea how it works, please give me some hint. Thanks.

Comment: Alloc `init` will do very little initialization compared with, say, initWithNibName or instantiation from a storyboard. The default implementation certainly won't initialize any subviews

Comment: Did you set up a xib/storyboard file along with your view controller?

Comment: Hi @danh , I have updated my article about instantiation, please take a look at it. Could you recommend any material about you say? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm stuck with just an iPhone today. Are you sure that page is declared strong? It may be that page is nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Check your IBOutlet is connected.
2. Check the method you are calling isn't called before the view is created from the storyboard/nib

## EDIT

The lines of code that you added, are overriding your getter. And every time you call self.page, your creating a new instance!

```
// It works if i remove the following code
- (ContentPageVC *)page
{
    if (_page) _page = [[ContentPageViewController alloc] init];

    return _page;
}
```

It should be like so:

```
// It works if i remove the following code
- (ContentPageVC *)page
{
    if (!_page) _page = [[ContentPageViewController alloc] init]; // Added the ! mark, only if nil you would create a new instance.

    return _page;
}
```

Plus you are calling alloc init on it, so Its not the same instance from storyboard!

So you should do this:

```
- (ContentPageVC *)page
{
    if (!_page) _page = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentPageViewController"];

    return _page;
}
```

And remove this lines of code:

```
   // instantiation from a storyboard
    ContentPageViewController *page = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ContentPageViewController"];
    self.page = page;
```

Every time you call "self.page" the override getter function will call. and return the same instance.

Comment: (1). I'm sure it's connected with the ContentPageViewController in the storyboard.

(2). I added some print code in the viewDidLoad of the ContentPageViewController. So I'm sure I updated the UI after it loaded.

Comment: From what function "updateUI" is called? viewDidLoad()? And are you using storyboards or nib files?

Comment: Sorry about I made you confuse, I have updated my code, please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @JhowLiu I'm happy I could help (: If this solved your problem, please accept my answer